# SQL Query To find the row which as maximum value with group by

Tags: mysql, database, looker-studio

I need a query to fetch the maximum combination's beverage name group by location.

Input:

[image]

Criteria:

1. it should fetch maximum combination
2. duplication of the location should not come
3. if combination value is same, then it should fetch the first row

Resulant:

[image]

Comment: on what criteria you got 3rd row in resultant, as for location_id 22 combination count is same so that time how do you want the result?(how can you define first row until you do any order on the table)

Comment: @Rams, We need to get the most sold product in each location using the SQL query.

Comment: You cannot meet the third criterion there is no way of establishing 1st row.

Comment: @P.Salmon I need to use this for google data studio, I have no other option

Comment: Data in sql is not stored in any order , unless you have something in your data which establishes the sequence of events such as an auto_increment column or date column then there is no way you can establish first row.

Comment: @P.Salmon, actually It's a result come from the subquery

https://mrkr.io/s/5e2fe0713792615f4d201dd9/0

Comment: And is there something in there which can establish the order of events?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
location_id,
FIRST_VALUE(beverage_name) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY location_id 
          ORDER BY combination_count DESC, beverage_id DESC) beverage_name,
FIRST_VALUE(beverage_id) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY location_id 
          ORDER BY combination_count DESC, beverage_id DESC) beverage_id,
FIRST_VALUE(combination_count) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY location_id 
          ORDER BY combination_count DESC, beverage_id DESC) combination_count 
FROM source_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I got some Syntax issues. Please find the screenshot below. Can you please help me out  

https://mrkr.io/s/5e2e81692cea917f0df7d45f/0

Comment: @sabeerzabi 1) You "forget" to specify your MySQL version. 2) You use some strange client which has its own opinion how SQL query must look like.

Comment: My Current MySQL version is 5.7.28. Let me change this?

Comment: Is there any other solution? I haven't any option to change

Comment: @sabeerzabi enumerate within the group using user-defined variables in a subquery, then select only 1st records.

Answer (score 0):

This is also an alternative code for the expected output:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM source_table
GROUP BY location_id;
```

Comment: I tried with same table and data as you gave and its working perfectly fine for me with expected output.

Comment: The capacity of this query to be executed depends on current SQL mode. The result, if capable, depends on current indices existed in the table. I.e. the query is close to non-applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple rank function ( need to derive the rank in Mysql) and get the result.

```
  select * from (           
      select location_id,beverage_name,beverage_id,combination_count,(case when location_id when @location_id then @curRank:=curRank+1 else @curRank:=1 and @location_id :=location_id end) as rank 
      from your_table t1,(SELECT @curRank := 0,@location_id :='') r 
         order by combination_count desc
    ) where rank=1;
```

Comment: OP has stated in akina's answer that Current MySQL version is 5.7.28 so this answer is inappropriate.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the comment, I have updated the solution to fit the version.